# Show that $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} x^k = 0$ for $x \in (0,1)$

Tags: calculus

I want to show that $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} x^k = 0$ for $x \in (0,1)$.

This makes intuitive sense but I can't figure out how I should go about proving it. Using the epsilon-delta definition I'd need to show that for every $\epsilon >0$ there is $M \in N$ such that
$$|x^k| < \epsilon \text { where } k \geq M$$
but I just can't figure out where to start.

Comment: Note: the absolute value signs around $x^k$ are unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints :

1. Show that it is a decreasing sequence bounded below.
2. Notice that $a_0 = x$, and $a_k = f(a_{k-1})$ where $f(y) = xy$. By (1), we know that $L = \lim a_k$ exists. Now
   $$
   a_k \to L \Rightarrow f(a_k) \to f(L)
   $$
   since $f$ is continuous. However, $f(a_k) = a_{k+1}$, and so the the sequences $\{f(a_k)\}$ and $\{a_k\}$ are actually *the same sequence.* Since a sequence cannot converge to two different points,
   $$
   L = f(L) = xL
   $$

Comment: I can show that it is a decreasing sequence and that there is a lower bound ($\inf x^k = 0$), but I am not sure about the second point why must the  limit satisfy that equation. It doesn't look like it is from the $\epsilon -\delta$ definition. Also, $L=0$ so that equation would be satisfied.

Comment: Use the fact that $f$ is continuous, so if $a_k := x^k$, then $a_k \to L$ implies that $f(a_k) \to f(L)$

Comment: I guess my question was where/what property is that from. Is that from a specific theorem? I have never approached a problem like this in the way you suggest which is why I am curious.

Comment: This is a common technique when a sequence is defined inductively : Given $a_0$, define $a_n = f(a_{n-1})$. If the limit exists and $f$ is continuous, then it must be a fixed point of $f$.

Comment: Right that makes sense for the first part, but the second part does not make any sense to me. Why must the limit satisfy that equation?

Comment: @rioneye : I have added an explanation in my post. Do have a look.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Could you please explain why you defined a continuous function $f$ to show the sequence converge? A bounded monotone sequence is convergent I think.

Comment: @MLT : I needed continuity to show that $L = f(L)$. The limit exists, of course, but we needed to find it as well.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Thanks, but don't you already have to show the bound is $0$ and hence $L=0$ when you prove part (1) ? Or do you prove part (1) is a different way?

Comment: No. Zero is a lower bound - how do you know it is the infimum (and hence the limit)?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x=\frac{1}{1+p} \text{for some}~  p>0 $

which implies  $|x^k|=\frac{1}{(1+p)^k} \leq \frac{1}{kp}<\epsilon~ \forall~ k>\frac{1}{p\epsilon} $

Comment: How did you come up with this step $\frac{1}{(1+p)^k} \leq \frac{1}{kp}$. It is not initially obvious to me.

Comment: The Bernoulli Inequalty says that $(1+p)^k\ge 1+kp$ (if $p\ge -1$). Straightforward induction proof. Or else one can use the Binomial Theorem.